# Trying to use SASS in Nativescript Angular App

Tags: sass, nativescript

I have created a nativescript angular app using "tns create my-app --template ng" in the nativescript cli, then installed the android platform with "tns platform add android".  The application then runs perfectly on the android emulator using "tns run android".

To enable the use of SASS for styling, I followed the instructions here "https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/theme".  This includes installing the SASS plugin and creating the basic scss files in the app directory.  Now, when I try to run my app I get the following error:

"First call of getPlatformData without providing projectData."

I have repeated the process a number of times but the result remains the same. Any ideas?  (Using nativescript v2.5)

Comment: What command did you run for the sass plugin exactly?

Comment: I used "tns install sass".

Comment: http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/videos/2016/03/14/less-sass.html This video might help and here (https://github.com/toddanglin/nativescript-dev-sass) is the sass plugin you need to dev with nativescript. `tns install sass` will try to install this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) which isn't what you want. I've never used Sass in my NS apps personally, but I'm guessing you don't have the bits installed that you need :) hopefully this info helps.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong on the command, but typically you'd install the package with the actual package name. Which would be https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-dev-sass `nativescript-dev-sass`

Comment: Thanks for your response @Brad.  I tried "npm install nativescript-dev-sass", and as you suspected, it was already installed probably by "tns install sass".  It was uninstalled and re-installed, but unfortunately getting the same error :-(

Comment: The NS CLI must have a hook that the CMD you used actually pulls the npm package I linked to so it's baked in. At any rate, I wish I had more info on using sass with NS. Might try pinging this on the official NS forum for some help from NS focused devs

Comment: i am facing same issue please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is related to changes in the NativeScript CLI versions 2.5.x that break the SASS plugin with LiveSync. I've updated the plugin tonight so that it will work with both NativeScript 2.4.x and with the upcoming NativeScript 3.0.

In NativeScript 2.5, the plugin *should* transpile SCSS to CSS, but LiveSync will not work correctly.

So for now, either downgrade your CLI to 2.4.2 OR try-out the new RC release for 3.0.0-rc. With either of these CLI versions installed, the SASS plugin should work again (with LiveSync).

Try the latest version of the plugin in your project by doing this:

```
   $ tns plugin remove nativescript-dev-sass
   $ npm install nativescript-dev-sass@rc --save-dev
```

Hopefully this works better. Sorry for the trouble.

*(NOTE: The plugin will drop the RC tag once {N} 3.0.0 officially ships)*

**UPDATE**

The changes to this plugin for {N} 2.5+ are now official and available simply by installing the latest version (no need for RC tag). If you're using {N} 2.4.2 or lower, it's still best to use the older version of this plugin. To install the older version:

```
$ npm install nativescript-dev-sass@0.4.2 --save-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Todd!  I have already ported my little project to nativescript 3.0 rc.  Tried the move to SASS again just now and it is working perfectly.  No trouble at all - guys like me are only to glad that there are guys like you out there who are prepared to make these kind of tools available for us :-)  

(Just one observation - I think the "--save-dev" parameter is only an npm thing.  Since nativescript compiles to an installable package that does not contain developer dependencies, it would probably not be needed anyway)

Comment: Glad it's working better for you! Additional improvements coming. And good catch on the syntax. You are correct that the NativeScript command does not need (or support) the --save-dev flag. Should have been: `npm install nativescript-dev-sass@rc --save-dev`

Comment: Wow thanks so much for posting this @Todd. I was stuck on this for at least a day. Thanks!!